# Remove Checkbox Alert When Unchecked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, alert

I have a list of checkboxes with unique IDs from cbox1 to cbox30 and I want different alerts to show when the user checks specific checkboxes such as,

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $( "#cbox1" ).on( "click", function() {
        alert("Day 1 Completed Well Done!!.");
    });

    $( "#cbox2" ).on( "click", function() {
        alert("Day 2 Finished Great Job.");
    });

    $( "#cbox3" ).on( "click", function() {
        alert("That's Day 3 Done, Keep it Up!.");
    });
});
```

Firstly is there an easier or more semantic way of doing this?

Secondly how can I remove the alert box if the user UNCHECKED the checkbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `data-*` attribute to store the message

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" class="cbox" data-msg="Day 1 Completed Well Done!!." />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" class="cbox" data-msg="Day 2 Finished Great Job." />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbox3" class="cbox" data-msg="That's Day 3 Done, Keep it Up!." />
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".cbox").on("click", function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            alert($(this).data('msg'));
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/976p4/)